# Is this a valid statement that would imply the Collatz Conjecture?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, collatz-conjecture

Let $f$ denote the Collatz transformation: $f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            {x\over 2} & \quad x\equiv 0 \mod 2 \\
            3x+1 & \quad x \equiv 1\mod 2
        \end{array}
    \right.$

Let $f^n(x)$ denote $n$ successive applications of $f$ to $x$.

Call a number $x\in\Bbb N$ convergent iff there exists $n\in \Bbb N$ such that $f^n(x) = 1$.

> **Proposition.** If, for any odd number $n$, $f^k(n) < n$ for some $k\in\Bbb N$, then all numbers are convergent (Collatz Conjecture).

We proceed by strong induction. The base case is trivial - 1 is convergent. Suppose $1,2,\dots,n-1$ are convergent. If $n$ is even, then $1\leq {n\over 2} < n$ is convergent by the inductive hypothesis and we are done. If $n$ is odd, by assumption we can find $k$ such that $f^k(n) < n$. But then $f^k(n)$ converges by the inductive hypothesis. The result follows.

If this is valid (which somehow I don't think it is), it gives an interesting outlook on the conjecture as asserting the non-existence of odd numbers that somehow "spiral out" infinitely under iteration of $f$. Is this proof correct, and if so, is it part of a typical description of the Collatz conjecture?

Comment: That argument is basically correct. If there is a non-convergent positive integer, there must be a smallest one, $m$ say, which clearly must be odd. None of the iterates of $m$ can be smaller than $m$, or $m$ would be convergent by minimality. That is essentially what your argument does.

Comment: Yea the argument is correct. If for all $n$ there exists a $k$ so that $f^{k}(n)<n$. Then since we know that $f^{k}(n)$ is a natural number we have that $f^{k}(n)\leq n-1$. Thus $f^{k}(n)<n\iff f^{k}(n)\leq n-1$ And since both $\frac{x}{2}$ and $3x+1$ are monotonic we can apply as many iterations of $f$ as we want to both sides of an inequality. Now by our last statement we also know that there exists a natural number $r$ for which $f^{r}(n-1)\leq n-2$ thus $f^{r+k}(n)=f^{r}(f^{k}(n))\leq f^{r}(n-1)\leq n-2$ and we can continue to repeat that argument until we get $f^{k+r+\cdots}(n)\leq1$.

Comment: I think too, that the argument and induction is correct. Whether it "is part of typical description": I think it is the concept of "stopping" time which might be introduced by R.Terras (see Lagarias' overview). T. Oliviera's pages work with it. (I'm formulating weak here because I've never tried to become specifically familiar with this view on the conjecture)

Comment: So the point of this argument is that is 'reduces" the Collatz problem to either finding an m for which $f^{k} (m) \geq {m} \forall {k} \in {N}$,  or somehow proving that's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this proof correct, and if so, is it part of a typical description of the Collatz conjecture?

The answers to these questions are yes, and yes. :)

Indeed, there are at least a couple of standard approaches that include this argument. For example, we can see that, if $n=4k+1$ for some positive integer $k$, then $n$ cannot be the smallest non-convergent odd number, because it leads to the trajectory: $$f(n)=12k+4,\\ f^2(n)=6k+2,\\ f^3(n)=3k+1<n.$$

Thus, if we seek the smallest odd number not converging to $1$, we need only consider odds of the form $4k+3$. Every number of the form $4k+3$ can either be written as $8k+3$ or as $8k+7$; these can then be written in only a few ways relative to $16, 32$, etc. At each step, we can follow the trajectory and see whether $n$ gets smaller in a few steps. Some cases, we cannot eliminate: $$8k+7\to 24k+22\to 12k+11\to 36k+34\to\\ 18k+17\to 54k+52 \to 27k+26\to  \,\,??,$$ and now we're stuck, because we don't know whether $27k+26$ is even or odd without knowing more about $k$. On the other hand: $$16k+3\to 48k+10\to 24k+5\to 72k+16\to\\ 36k+8\to 18k+4\to 9k+2 < n,$$

So any number of the form $16k+3$ is guaranteed to reduce, and we needn't consider $32k+3$ or $32k+19$.

This line of reasoning has been followed, and although we can narrow down the list of candidates for the smallest odd non-convergent, we cannot reduce it to nothing.

---

Taking a different approach, one can define a stopping-time function $h(n)=\min\{k:f^k(n)<n\}$, with $h(n)=\infty$ if all iterates remain larger than or equal to $n$. The Collatz conjecture is then equivalent to the claim that $h(n)<\infty$ for all $n>1$. This function has also been studied, but its properties are not nice in a way that yields to any obvious analysis, which becomes clear if you start playing with it.